# Save python matplotlib figure as pickle

Tags: python, matplotlib, pickle

I want to save matplotlib figures as pickle, to enable my team to easily load them and investigate anomalous events. Using a simple image format loses the ability to zoom-in and investigate the figure. So I tried to pickle my figure:

```
fig, axarr = plt.subplots(2, sharex='all') # creating the figure
... # plotting things
...
pickle.dump(fig, open('myfigfile.p'), 'wb'))
```

Then I load it. Looks good. At first.

```
fig = pickle.load(open('myfigfile.p', 'rb'))
plt.show()
```

But then I see that sharex doesn't work. When I zoom-in on one subplot, the other remains static. On the original plot this works great, and zooming-in zooms on both x-axis, but after I pickle-load the figure, this doesn't work anymore.
How can I save the plot so that it continues to share-x after loading?
Or, how can I reinstate share-x after loading the figure from the pickle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the current development version of matplotlib this should work due to the [fix provided](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/11544).

With the current released version of matplotlib, would need to reestablish the sharing e.g. like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pickle

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, sharey="row")
axes[0].plot([0,1],[0,1])
axes[1].plot([0,1],[1,2])
axes[2].plot([0,1],[2,3])

pickle.dump(fig, file('fig1.pkl', 'wb'))  

plt.close("all")

fig2 = pickle.load(file('fig1.pkl','rb'))
ax_master = fig2.axes[0]
for ax in fig2.axes:
    if ax is not ax_master:
        ax_master.get_shared_y_axes().join(ax_master, ax)

plt.show()
```

This has the drawback that you need to know which axes to share. In the case of all axes being shared this is of course easy, as shown above.

Comment: Awesome. This is *exactly* what I needed. I only changed get_shared_y_axes to get_shared_x_axes, since I don't want zooming-in to affect y, only x. Thanks!